Can proliferate give my creatures that have a +1/+1 by another creature's ability that leaves once said creature leaves?
Let’s say I have a bunch of Saprolings with +1/+1 due to Verdeloth the Ancient’s ability. Can proliferate add another counter to those Saprolings if that is the only counter they have?

No, you are confusing counters with power/toughness changes in general. Verdeloth the Ancient does not give creatures +1/+1 counters, or any type of counter. A counter is a physical thing that you put on a creature that has some sort of game effect. Verdeloth the Ancient simply has an ability that causes other creatures to have increased power and toughness as long as you control it.
Proliferate only interacts with counters. It will not do anything to a creature just because that creature currently has its power and toughness increased by another effect.

122.1. A counter is a marker placed on an object or player that modifies its characteristics and/or interacts with a rule, ability, or effect.

Compare the wording on Verdeloth to something like Ajani's Pridemate.

Whenever you gain life, put a +1/+1 counter on Ajani's Pridemate.

Note that Verdeloth does not say to put a counter on your creatures.
